# Bootstrap 4 beta server side validation after fixing error

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, validation, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4.0.0.beta, and I can add server-side validation by adding `.is-invalid` classes to inputs which were invalid upon submission. However, when a user fixes their error in this input (for example by filling an input that is required and was left unfilled), the input still has the `.is-invalid` class, so I think this can be somewhat confusing to the user, because they can think that the input is still invalid (even if it is not).

What would the most elegant way to address this be? I'm thinking either combine client-side validation or just listen for changes on inputs with the `.is-invalid` class via Javascript, and whenever they are filled, remove the class.

Answer (score 0):

This should be achieved by using Javascript.

If a keyup event suffice, you can do this :

**inline Javascript**

```
<input type="text" class="is-invalid" onkeyup="this.classList.remove('is-invalid')">
```

**jQuery**

```
<input type="text" class="is-invalid">
```

-

```
$('input').keyup(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('is-invalid');
});
```